# SDK AutoCompleteBox Ignores IsTabStop odd issue

Tags: xaml, silverlight, keyboard, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I've got a few sdk AutoCompleteBox's that I just want to set `IsTabStop="False"` on. If you do so it's ignored and still takes focus/tab action.

So I went digging into [the template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728668%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and found the embedded TextBox in there with it explicitly hardcoded to `IsTabStop=True` so I figured I could just pull that out, TemplateBind to an unused property like `Tag` to set it at the instance level and just provide a setter in the template for default True, right?

No joy though, it still ignores it. So I tried just setting it `False` explicitly in the template. Which sure enough removes it from the Tab order. HOWEVER, it also disables the control so it won't accept focus or edit at all.

I've ran into similar situations in the past but none of my tricks are working. Anyone ran into this before? What am I missing to just make the damn thing fall out of tab order? I'm also rather confused why setting the IsTabStop on the embedded TextBox would disable the control from all hittestvisibility....

Not sure where the reasoning is for setting  to just have the property ignored nor have found explanation in any docs yet.

So, maybe another pair of eyes might help before I go too far down the rabbit hole for something seemingly so simple, any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextBox` inside the `AutoCompleteBox` can only own keyboard focus when all [criteria for focus ownership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903954(VS.95).aspx) are met:

- must be derived from `Control`
- must be enabled
- must be visible
- must be loaded (how to test: `Loaded` event fired / visual parent in not null anymore [I use an extension method `IsLoaded`])
- and... `IsTabStop` must be true

Therefore you have to let the internal `TextBox` have its tabstoppy ways.
But we have other options.
I thought about using a `ContentControl` and setting `TabNavigation="Once"`. As far as I understood it is supposed to have the Control and all its content behave like one solid piece in the tab navigation chain, so theoretically when tabbing you will step at the ContentControl, but never down into its content.

But I tried it and it is not working as expected. Don't know where my thinking is wrong here.

I played around with it and found the following solution is working:

Surround them with a `FocusDitcher` (we derive from ContentControl und make the control ditch the focus `OnGotFocus`, but not if triggered by the user clicking into the inner TextBox). We could alternatively write a `Behavior` for that. For focus ditching, the control has to sabotage one of the prerequisites for focus ownership, like going to disabled mode and back to enabled (not working with IsTabStop, tried it, failed).

```
// helper control
public class FocusCatcher : Control { }

[TemplatePart( Name = "ReversedTabSequenceEntryPointElement", Type = typeof( UIElement ) )]
public class FocusDitcher : ContentControl
{
    public FocusDitcher()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof( FocusDitcher );
        TabNavigation = KeyboardNavigationMode.Once;
    }

    private UIElement m_reversedTabSequenceEntryPoint;

    protected override void OnGotFocus( RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() == this)
        {
            DitchFocus();
        }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        m_reversedTabSequenceEntryPoint = (UIElement) GetTemplateChild( "ReversedTabSequenceEntryPointElement" );
        m_reversedTabSequenceEntryPoint.GotFocus += OnReversedTabSequenceEntryPointGotFocus;
    }

    private void OnReversedTabSequenceEntryPointGotFocus( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        // tweak tab index to ensure that when we ditch the focus it will go to the first one in the tab order
        // otherwise it would not be possible to ever shift+tab back to any element precceeding this one in the tab order
        var localTabIndexValue = ReadLocalValue(TabIndexProperty);
        TabIndex = Int32.MinValue;
        DitchFocus();

        if (DependencyProperty.UnsetValue == localTabIndexValue)
            ClearValue( TabIndexProperty );
        else
            TabIndex = (int) localTabIndexValue;

    }

    private void DitchFocus()
    {
        IsEnabled = false; // now we lose the focus and it should go to the next one in the tab order
        IsEnabled = true;  // set the trap for next time
    }
}
```

and template

```
<Style TargetType="myApp:FocusDitcher">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="myApp:FocusDitcher">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <myApp:FocusCatcher x:Name="ReversedTabSequenceEntryPointElement"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Damnit Martin, I have got to make my way your area and buy you some beers (if you drink that is) sooner rather than later man. Have to swing back to this after morning standups but thanks in advance as usual brother!

Comment: Oh that would be great. Really. Let me know when you plan to visit Germany.

Comment: Thanks, shoot me an email so I have yours, would be happy to have a few mass biers. In fact, bier ist immer willkommen :)

Comment: Ich verstehe viel und nicht verloren gehen. Langsam lernen. Halten Sie versuchen, herauszufinden, einen Weg über in .ch oder .de zu leben, weil ich es liebe es. Except I struggle still in conversation, your English is far more fluent than my deutsch. Why? Was geht? Or just shoot me an email we can talk off here. :)

Comment: Guten morgen :) I noticed my approach is not working, played around with it, and posted an update. Maybe you want to try that one out.

Comment: Jeez man, you're far too generous with your time and I fear neither of us are walking home after I repay all the beer owed haha. I only briefly got a chance to look at your stuff yesterday so I didn't even get to test it. I have an idea though for another way to solve this that's a trick I used to have to use in some of the SL embedded stuff. Will return with the outcome at some point. Thanks man und guten morgen! :D

Comment: Ok so what I ended up doing instead, was I just bound the `IsTabStop` on the embedded TextBox to the template. I set the instance to `IsTabStop=False` Then I just put two EventTriggers on the control instance. One for `MouseLeftButtonDown` and one for `LostFocus` the click does a `ChangePropertyAction` to turn `IsTabStop` to True, and the `LostFocus` returns `IstabStop` False. Works like a charm and no codebehind. Still counting yours as answer if not for sharing your time and it's correct also. Sorry it took so long to swing back to this, super busy month, thanks again mein freund!

Comment: Sounds like a nice and small solution. Why didn't I think of that? :D

Comment: Eh, it was one of those-one off adhoc scenarios for just 3 textbox's in a very special instance. Beers is still owed either way lol.